# Upload de múltiplos arquivos com Node.js

Tags: node.js, upload, file-upload, express.js, multiple-file-upload

Estou tentando fazer o upload de múltiplos arquivos com Node.js, mas não consigo fazer a parte do servidor.

Estou usando ExpressJS como framework, e se precisar posso usar outros pacotes para facilitar esta tarefa.

Por enquanto, estou usando o `express.bodyParser()` e inspecionando o upload com `console.log(req.files)`, mas isso só me apresenta um dos arquivos.

No cliente o `input` está marcado como `multiple` e a `form` está com `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: O nome do `input` esta com colchetes `input type="file" name="nome[]" ...`, para ser enviado como array?

Comment: @abfurlan Não, isso é necessário?

Comment: Sim, para upload multiplo sim.

Comment: @abfurlan Vou fazer a alteração. Poste isso como resposta, se funcionar eu aprovo.

Comment: Me avise se funcionar então posto.

Comment: Uma vez tive o mesmo problema com PHP. Depois de uns 2 dias revirando o código inteiro, descobri que era só adicionar colchetes no `input` pra funcionar. HTML trollou total com esse requisito.

Comment: @Kazzkiq Aconteceu o mesmo comigo em PHP, por isso sugeri tentar, pode ser isso.

Comment: Deu certo, adiciona a resposta que eu aceito, e complemento com a parte server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para upload múltiplo de arquivos o atributo `name` do `input` deve ser seguido de `[]`, assim os arquivos serão enviados como `array`

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="nome[]" multiple />
</form>
```

Se utilizado o atributo `name` sem notação de `array`, o servidor irá substituir o nome do arquivo anterior para o mais recente, usando a notação, você informa para o servidor que deseja ter vários campos com o mesmo nome, e esses são adicionados em um `array`.

**Complementando com a parte do servidor:**

No servidor, os arquivos ficam numa array dentro de `req.files.nome[0]` por exemplo. Note que a array **é** o primeiro item de `req.files.nome`, e não o objeto em si. Inspecionando `req.files.nome[0]` eu recebo um objeto com uma estrutura como essa:

```js
[ { fieldName: 'nome[]',
    originalFilename: 'Arquivo1.png',
    path: 'caminho/local/temporario/do/arquivo.png',
    headers:
     { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="nome[]"; filename="Arquivo1.
png"',
       'content-type': 'image/png' },
    ws:
     { _writableState: [Object],
       writable: true,
       domain: null,
       _events: [Object],
       _maxListeners: 10,
       path: 'caminho/local/temporario/do/arquivo.png',
       fd: null,
       flags: 'w',
       mode: 438,
       start: undefined,
       pos: undefined,
       bytesWritten: 1008705,
       closed: true },
    size: 1008705,
    name: 'Arquivo1.png',
    type: 'image/png' }, // (outros arquivos...)
}
```